# How to open dialog styled activity from notification without previous activity closing?

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

1. I have an Activity with dialog style so it visually opens on top of previous activity.
2. I have a notification which opens this activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CalcActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
((NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(0, builder.build());
```

The problem is that when user taps my notification, previous visible activity closes, home screen appears and my dialog is displayed on top of home screen. How to prevent closing of previous activity? Please note that previous activity might not come from my app.

Comment: Have you tried different PendingIntent flags? Just guessing...

Comment: Tried to no effect. A lot of flags and manually searching for right combination is an overkill. Searched through Google, but all topics are focused on own activity stack, which is easily manageable.

I have another app and it opens as a dialog on top of current app, but it is replying to an intent generated by current app, so no problems there.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent as below :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml` register activity and use theme as `dialog`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog"/>
```