# return to previous activity not working as intended

Tags: android

So I have a notification which open an activity:

```
public void showNotification(View v) {

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setContentTitle("title text");
    builder.setContentText("text");
    builder.setOngoing(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondClass.class);
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(SecondClass.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    final NotificationManager NM = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NM.notify(0, builder.build());
```

The activity i made is a simple dialog styled activity. When i open the activity from the notification drawer, on top of any other app, like facebook, whatsapp, chrome browser and so on, the activity open as intended. 
**The problem is when i try to close it, and go back to the previous app.**

When i click on the back button, to close my dialog styled activity, i go back straight to the phone's home screen, instead back to the previous app. Why?

When i click a "close" button i have created at the dialog:

```
 close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SecondClass.this.finish();

            }
        });
```

Same thing happening: the activity is finished, but i'm going back to the home screen, instead to the previous app. why??

*note: the previous app is still working at the background, even after i finish my activity.

While searching solutions i found this link:
[How to open dialog styled activity from notification without previous activity closing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968559/how-to-open-dialog-styled-activity-from-notification-without-previous-activity-c)

but no solution was given.

P.S. I'm new to android developing, if possible, please make it simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for long i found a solution at this link:
[Go back to previous screen on backbutton pressed after responding to notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888013/go-back-to-previous-screen-on-backbutton-pressed-after-responding-to-notificatio)

apparently there were 2 problems in my code. First, as it was explained at the link, i did not use `.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);`

Second,according to: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_notifications.htm i shouldn't use a stack builder. A stack builder will contain an artificial back stack for the started Activity. This ensures that navigating backward from the Activity leads out of your application to the Home screen. And this is not what i wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You looks like meet the same problem Regular Activity & Special Activity for Notification' Action, any My answer Here : [After notification button return to original activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526086/after-notification-button-return-to-original-activity/33568060#33568060)

Comment: Hey friend. if you check the code i posted you will see i do have what you suggest at your link `final PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` Maybe i did something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**I faced the same issue using stack builder in my case it was fixed by  :**

replacing

```
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_IMMUTABLE
```

to

`PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or FLAG_MUTABLE`